# web3 in react-native : Cannot read property 'getReader'

Tags: react-native, promise, ethereum, web3js

#### Version

"web3": "^1.2.1"
"react-native": "0.59.10"

From [set-up tutorial](https://gist.github.com/dougbacelar/29e60920d8fa1982535247563eb63766) and https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1022, I was able to install `web3` in `react-native`, however I got this error:

#### Error

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getReader' of undefined
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getReader' of undefined
> at new exports.IncomingMessage (blob:http://localhost:8081/4f48abd1-1bd3-445a-bdbc-3cdeca3a37a2:222317:34)
> at module.exports.ClientRequest._connect (blob:http://localhost:8081/4f48abd1-1bd3-445a-bdbc-3cdeca3a37a2:222201:22)
> at blob:http://localhost:8081/4f48abd1-1bd3-445a-bdbc-3cdeca3a37a2:222115:14
> at tryCallOne (blob:http://localhost:8081/4f48abd1-1bd3-445a-bdbc-3cdeca3a37a2:45372:14)
> at blob:http://localhost:8081/4f48abd1-1bd3-445a-bdbc-3cdeca3a37a2:45473:17
> at blob:http://localhost:8081/4f48abd1-1bd3-445a-bdbc-3cdeca3a37a2:46351:21
> at _callTimer (blob:http://localhost:8081/4f48abd1-1bd3-445a-bdbc-3cdeca3a37a2:46240:9)
> at _callImmediatesPass (blob:http://localhost:8081/4f48abd1-1bd3-445a-bdbc-3cdeca3a37a2:46276:9)
> at Object.callImmediates (blob:http://localhost:8081/4f48abd1-1bd3-445a-bdbc-3cdeca3a37a2:46495:14)
> at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (blob:http://localhost:8081/4f48abd1-1bd3-445a-bdbc-3cdeca3a37a2:16572:16)`

The error occurs when I doing promise method like `web3.eth.getTransactionCount` or `web3.eth.getBlock('latest')`.

I tried `console.log(web3.version)`, no problem at all

Comment: Show me the code you're trying, not the link you studied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out using `web3@1.0.0-beta.34` is more stable for `react-native`, so the question mentioned problem does not appear anymore.